Beautify seaborn graph of temporal data
I am trying to beautify a graph to make it easier to read and understand the data present. The data in question is time series data for when a button was pressed. I want to graphically represent the data as it would potentially show details about press frequency during a time window.
I have generated a graph somewhat that represents what I would like to observe, though it is difficult to read given the volume of data.
below is the code I use to generate the graph and some sample data to show the result,
date_list = ['2024/07/27, 22:00:34', '2024/07/27, 21:51:34', '2024/07/27, 21:29:00', '2024/07/27, 21:15:21', '2024/07/27, 21:07:55', '2024/07/28, 21:03:56', '2024/07/28, 20:36:41', '2024/07/28, 20:22:58', '2024/07/28, 20:09:17', '2024/07/28, 20:04:49', '2024/07/29, 20:02:07', '2024/07/29, 19:37:25', '2024/07/29, 17:51:23', '2024/07/29, 17:47:29', '2024/07/29, 17:00:28', '2024/07/30, 16:42:06', '2024/07/30, 16:11:29', '2024/07/30, 16:08:18', '2024/07/30, 15:50:38', '2024/07/30, 15:36:45', '2024/07/30, 15:23:23', '2024/07/31, 15:12:04', '2024/07/31, 15:08:42', '2024/07/31, 15:00:46', '2024/07/31, 14:41:30']

compare_date = datetime.date(1066, 1, 1)
compare_time = datetime.time(12, 00, 00)

dt_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns=["bt_dates"])
dt_df["bt_dates"] = dt_df["bt_dates"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S"))

dt_df["time"] = dt_df["bt_dates"].apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(compare_date, x.time()))
dt_df["date"] = dt_df["bt_dates"].apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(x.date(), compare_time))

f, ax = pyplot.subplots()
(
   seaborn_objects.Plot(dt_df, x="time", y="date")
    .add(seaborn_objects.Dash(), seaborn_objects.Dodge(), orient="y")
    .scale(y=seaborn_objects.Temporal().tick(upto=100))
    .on(ax)
    .plot()
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M', ))


The next step is the change the dates on the y axis to red based on if it is a weekday or weekend and add grayed areas for hours when people would be asleep / awake. But here is where I am lost as I have only just stared working with seaborn objects and I do not fully understand them yet.
How do I alter the coloring of the y axis using seaborn objects?

I have solved the issue in regard to changing the color of the text on the axis. To do so, one needs to pull the axis tick information and then run through the list. The code below will change the color of the text.
date_list = ['2024/07/27, 22:00:34', '2024/07/27, 21:51:34', '2024/07/27, 21:29:00', '2024/07/27, 21:15:21', '2024/07/27, 21:07:55', '2024/07/28, 21:03:56', '2024/07/28, 20:36:41', '2024/07/28, 20:22:58', '2024/07/28, 20:09:17', '2024/07/28, 20:04:49', '2024/07/29, 20:02:07', '2024/07/29, 19:37:25', '2024/07/29, 17:51:23', '2024/07/29, 17:47:29', '2024/07/29, 17:00:28', '2024/07/30, 16:42:06', '2024/07/30, 16:11:29', '2024/07/30, 16:08:18', '2024/07/30, 15:50:38', '2024/07/30, 15:36:45', '2024/07/30, 15:23:23', '2024/07/31, 15:12:04', '2024/07/31, 15:08:42', '2024/07/31, 15:00:46', '2024/07/31, 14:41:30']

compare_date = datetime.date(1066, 1, 1)
compare_time = datetime.time(12, 00, 00)

dt_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns=["bt_dates"])
dt_df["bt_dates"] = dt_df["bt_dates"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S"))

dt_df["time"] = dt_df["bt_dates"].apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(compare_date, x.time()))
dt_df["date"] = dt_df["bt_dates"].apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(x.date(), compare_time))

f, ax = pyplot.subplots()
(
   seaborn_objects.Plot(dt_df, x="time", y="date")
    .add(seaborn_objects.Dash(), seaborn_objects.Dodge(), orient="y")
    .scale(y=seaborn_objects.Temporal().tick(upto=100))
    .on(ax)
    .plot()
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M', ))
for tick_label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    tick_date = datetime.strptime(tick_label.get_text(), "%Y-%m-%d")
    if tick_date.weekday() > 4:
        tick_label.set_color("red")


